# CREATE table of date type and use its default value as CURRENT_DATE on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried running below code in sql command, but the  code line `start_date date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE` had issues, got no idea why. I needed only date.

But if I replace that with `start_date datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
the SQL will run but the idea is I only need to store date and not datetime.

How do I do it without using timestamp and latter converting to only date?

```
CREATE TABLE advertisement (
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    summary text DEFAULT null,
    featured_image varchar(50) DEFAULT null, 
    start_date date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    end_date date not null,
    link text DEFAULT null,
    added_date datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_date datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: And what would those issues be?

Comment: I need to store current date by default on start_date..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) is quite clear that this works for `datetime` columns but not `date` columns:

> This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date
>   column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`.
>   The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default
>   for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns.

If you really have your heart set on ignoring the time component, you will have to use a trigger to set the value, rather than a `default` constraint.

Comment: Query error:
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'start_date'

Comment: I know like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP there is also CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_TIME in SQL but when does it come to use ..then

Comment: @AhsitTamang . . . You can use them all over the place.  But not as default values for columns.

Comment: Thank you so much..for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

as of MySQL8 this is now legal,

```
CREATE TABLE t (
d DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)
);
```

note however that the "extra" parentheses is *IMPORTANT*, because, [for unknown reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880064/in-mysql8-why-does-date-default-current-date-need-parentheses-around-current-dat), this is somehow illegal:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
d DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way I was able to use `CURRENT_DATE` function. This code is 100% tested. Note, date value of that instance of point when new row is added is saved.

I used following, SQL first:

```
CREATE TABLE advertisement (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  summary text DEFAULT NULL,
  featured_image varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  start_date date DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date date NOT NULL,
  link text DEFAULT NULL,
  added_date datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_date datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

and then during adding SQL I used query as

```
INSERT INTO `advertisement` SET
start_date=CURRENT_DATE(),
end_date='2018-04-02',
added_date='2018-03-01 00:10:33'
```

Thank you all for your suggestion.

Comment: Note that answer posts are not for follow-up questions. If you have some doubts about your solution, then you can either ask a new question, or if it is closely related, an update to the question is sometimes OK. Bear in mind that if your question edit invalidates existing answers, the update is probably better as a new question. Thank you!