# in mysql8 why does DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE need parentheses around CURRENT_DATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, default, create-table

as of mysql8, this is legal:

```
CREATE TABLE t (d DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

and this is legal:

```
CREATE TABLE t (d DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE));
```

so why is this illegal?

```
CREATE TABLE t (d DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);
```

resulting in a

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'CURRENT_DATE)' at line 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to [this for more information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).

This is most likely, what you were referring to in your question:

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal
> constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression
> default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal
> constant default values.
>
> [...]
>
> The exception is that, for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns, you can
> specify the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function as the default, without
> enclosing parentheses.

Comment: When do literal constants and expressions clash?